# Sorting and grouping depending on the field value with MySQL

Tags: mysql, sorting, group-by

My table consists of two columns:

```
id | my_group
-------------
1  | 3
2  | 2
3  | 1
4  | no_group
5  | 3
6  | 1
7  | 2
8  | 3
9  | no_group
10 | 1
```

Can you please help me to get the correct sorting order presented below, using using MySQL?

```
id | my_group
-------------
10 | 1
6  | 1
3  | 1
9  | no_group
8  | 3
5  | 3
1  | 3
7  | 2
2  | 2
4  | no_group
```

The `my_group` column is sorted descending but if `my_group` is not equal "no_group", `my_group` should group the results first.

Comment: What queries have you tried so far?

Comment: Select * from table order by my_group asc

Comment: @Undefined_variable - the query you wrote would return only 4 results.

Comment: @Strawberry - Let's imagine you have a database with transactions. Id is a transaction number. Some clients may purchase more than one item. In the case of these clients I need to group their purchases  so that the transactions appear as presented in the second table. My_group means that a client bought more than 1 item. If some client bought only one item, the my_group field value is no_group.

Comment: Nope. Still don't get it. What determines th order of the results - 1 then no_group then 3 then 2 then no_group.

Comment: Id determines the order unless a record with my_group!="no_group" is found. If a record with my_group!="no_group" is found (for example my_group equal 1), the query should look for further occurence of this my_group value in the table and list them directly after the first occurence.

Answer (score 1):

You could get this complicated order with following statement:

```
SELECT
    e.id,
    e.my_group
FROM
    example e
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        MAX(e1.id) maxid,
        e1.my_group
    FROM
        example e1
    WHERE
        e1.my_group <> 'no_group'
    GROUP BY e1.my_group
) t
ON
    e.my_group = t.my_group
ORDER BY COALESCE(t.maxid, id) DESC, id DESC;
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/95527/2)

**Explanation:**

We do a left join with the subselect that returns the maximum id per group, if there is a group.

The result of

```
SELECT
    e.id,
    e.my_group,
    t.maxid,
    COALESCE(t.maxid, e.id)
FROM
    example e
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        MAX(e1.id) maxid,
        e1.my_group
    FROM
        example e1
    WHERE
        e1.my_group <> 'no_group'
    GROUP BY e1.my_group
) t
ON
    e.my_group = t.my_group
```

is

```
id  my_group  maxid  COALESCE(t.maxid, e.id)
10  1         10     10
 6  1         10     10
 3  1         10     10
 9  no_group  NULL    9
 5  3         8       8
 1  3         8       8
 8  3         8       8
 2  2         7       7
 7  2         7       7
 4  no_group  NULL    4
```

So for the rows with 'no_group' we get NULL in our `maxid` column. For these rows we've got to take the id. [COALESCE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) returns the first non-null value of it's arguments, so it returns the maximum id per group and the id value for the rows with 'no_group'.

**Note:**

If there would be `NULL` values instead of the string 'no_group' then you could simply omit the `WHERE` clause of the subselect. I would prefer this.

Comment: You're a friggin' genius. How you got that from the information provided, I've no idea!

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks. First I didn't get it too. But there was that comment, that said, that every no_group was principally "a group with a single item". Then I saw the pattern, that the order was by the greatest id per group. Getting the greatest id for the no_group values was simpler than I thought.

Comment: @Strawberry I forgot to sort within the same group. Added `, id DESC` to ORDER BY clause.